# declaring variables faster than setState

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, expo

My team and I are working on a Profile Page that shows Profile Picture and Bio. We used expo-image-picker library for users to select the image they want and show the image on the app. I would also like to upload the Image to s3 where the images of the employee will be stored. The problem I am facing right now is that the params.ImageUri is giving me the local file instead of the s3 link. This is what my functions look like.

I have a selectImage() function that will trigger the user to select an image from their gallery. Then the data will be stored in the **this.state.items[0].imageUrl**, which is the data that is from the Web API. After I call this function, the value of **this.state.items[0].imageUrl** is the local file. This function is called when the user presses on their **Profile Picture**.

```
  selectImage = async () => {

    const cancelImageUrl = this.state.items[0].imageUrl

    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1
    });

    const file = {
      uri: result.uri,
      name: 'IMG_' + Math.random(4000),
      type: 'image/jpg'
    }

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.map((item, i) =>
          i == 0 ?
            { ...item, imageUrl: file.uri } : item),
        file: file
      })
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.map((item, i) =>
          i == 0 ?
            { ...item, imageUrl: cancelImageUrl } : item)
      })
    }
  }
```

Upon pressing on the Save button, I would like to upload the image to s3, saving the file in the cloud so that users will be able to see the application whenever they open it. Here, when I log the state of **items[0].imageUrl**, it displays the s3 link.

```
uploadImage = () => {
    let file = this.state.file;
   let config = this.state.config;
    RNS3.put(file, config)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.headers.Location);
        this.setState({
          items: this.state.items.map((item, i) =>
            i == 0 ?
              { ...item, imageUrl: response.headers.Location } : item)
        })
        console.log('This is the state of items[0].imageUri ' + this.state.items[0].imageUrl)
      })
  }
```

So, here I decided to first, upload the Image to the s3 and set the state of **items[0].imageUrl** to the link. then set the value of params as the imageUrl, then update the WebAPI by calling updateProfileData(params). The problem I'm currently facing is that when I press Save, the alert that pops up from my screen shows that the state of **items[0].imageUrl** is the local file. Only after I press the Save button again that the alert shows the state of **items[0].imageUrl** as the s3 link.

```
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
              onPress={() => {
                this.uploadImage();
                let params = {
                  ImageUrl: this.state.items[0].imageUrl,
                  EmployeeBio: this.state.items[0].employeeBio
                };
                alert('This is params, ' + params.ImageUrl);
                this.updateProfileData(params);
              }}>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Save</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

My team and I are unable to solve this problem... Thank you for the help!

Comment: Hi. This is probably due to the fact that `setState` is asynchronous, so putting the alert immediately after it in your `uploadImage` function will not show the true value it's being set to. Put your alert somewhere else that's not in the same JS thread and you will see the correct value once `setState` is actually complete (like in your render function before you return the components. The reason you're seeing it the second time you press save is because it's showing you the value of the previous state before the new state value has been set (and is complete)

Comment: So, is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: I put the alert there because when it calls the ```updateProfileData(params)```, the imageUrl keeps being local file and I would like ```params.ImageUrl``` to be the s3 link. Is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing things in a synchronous JS thread when `setState` is an asynchronous function. The way to solve this is by using the callback argument in the `setState` function (the second argument passed in, which will get executed after the state has been set) and execute your `updateProfileData` code there instead.

See here for an explanation - https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296

So to fix your issue you should do something like this:

**Component**

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}
    onPress={() => this.uploadImage()}>
   <View>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Save</Text>
   </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

**uploadImage**

```
uploadImage = () => {
    let file = this.state.file;
   let config = this.state.config;
    RNS3.put(file, config)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.headers.Location);
        this.setState({
          items: this.state.items.map((item, i) =>
            i == 0 ?
              { ...item, imageUrl: response.headers.Location } : item)
        },
        // This is your callback
        () => {
            let params = {
                  ImageUrl: this.state.items[0].imageUrl,
                  EmployeeBio: this.state.items[0].employeeBio
                };
            alert('This is params, ' + params.ImageUrl);
            this.updateProfileData(params);
        })
      })
  }
```